# How do I select the last but 10 rows from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, syntax, row, limit

I want to run this query

```
select *
from  table
order asc
limit N;
```

where N is the total number of rows minus 10.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM table)
```

returns the total as 189 so, in this case, I would want my limit to be 179

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If order is not important, you can use the offset of `limit`:

Note, there is no actual value for 'Until End Of Table'. The [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) suggests to use "some large number" for the second parameter.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
order by ID DESC
LIMIT 10, 999999999999999
```

If you do want in in ascending order you can apply a different ordering afterwards:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT *
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY ID DESC
  LIMIT 10, 999999999999999) x
ORDER BY
  ID ASC
```

Comment: Inventive answer! You can also use a stored proc to define the limit the OP was looking for, but I suspect it's beyond reqs/out-of-scope here.

Comment: Yes, in a stored procedure (or PHP) you could query the count first to determine the limit. That may even be faster. Another possibility, especially when used from PHP, is just to query everything and ignore the latest 10 rows. However, I think a solution in a single query is to be preferred, unless it makes the query overly complex or too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the most efficient one, but this should work if you only have one field as a primary key.

```
select *
from T1
where
    T1.id not in (
        select top(10) id
        from T1
        order by id desc
    )
order by
    id;
```

It will get the last rows by your order and then you can exclude by the key.

**Edit:**

Better yet, instead of not in, you can use a left outer join.

```
select 
    T1.*
from T1
left outer join ( select top(10) id from Enums_Tables order by id desc ) as T2
on
    T1.id = T2.id
where
    T2.id is null;
```